# how to get user control data when it's load dynamicly

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

i have a user control that have some properties.

```
public partial class ImageUpload : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Image img = new Image();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img.PG_Caption = txtImgCaption.Text;
        img.PG_Visible = chkVisible.Checked;
        img.File = fileImgUpload.FileBytes;
        img.PG_FileName = fileImgUpload.FileName;
    }
}
```

on another user control i load on page_load some of the first user control.

```
public partial class ImagesTab : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images
    {
        get { return GetImages(); }
    }

    private List<Image> GetImages()
    {
        List<Image> lI = new List<Image>();
        foreach (Control ctl in plhImages.Controls)
        {

        }
        return lI;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                Control ImageUpload = LoadControl("ImageUpload.ascx");
                plhImages.Controls.Add(ImageUpload);
                Literal li = new Literal();
                li.Text = "<br />";
                plhImages.Controls.Add(li);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

how to implement the foreach loop on GetImages() to get the data ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<Image> GetImages()
{
    List<Image> lI = new List<Image>();
    foreach (Control ctl in plhImages.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is ImageUpload) lI.Add(((ImageUpload)ctl).img);
    }
    return lI;
}
```

Comment: it's seems that i don't have controls after the postback.

Comment: @eyalb: Where are you using this `GetImage()` method?